# How to float different height elements independently without container div

Tags: html, css

I have two columns with elements floated to opposite sides, but when the content of an element exceeds the minimum height it ends up on the other side. Using `clear:left` keeps the elements in their correct place, but causes the elements on the other side to be pushed down when the content exceeds the minimum height.

Here's what I'm after http://jsfiddle.net/93Ljqb36/4/

...but using the below mark up that doesn't wrap the elements in floated divs

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="foo left">LEFT 1</div>
    <div class="foo right">
        RIGHT 1...
        The purple elements below are floated right, but end up on the left when content exceeds minimum height. I also need to avoid pushing the elements on the left down when content exceeds height. How do I keep floated elements on the same side without using more divs as this is meant to be a responsive design.. 
    </div>
    <div class="foo left">LEFT 2</div>
    <div class="foo right">RIGHT 2</div>
    <div class="foo left">LEFT 3</div>
    <div class="foo right">RIGHT 3</div>    
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/93Ljqb36/5/

Comment: I think that you **need** to make container divs. One div for the left hand side and one div for the right hand side. What's the hassle about them?

Comment: I need the design to be responsive so I cannot have the elements placed within floated divs as it messes up up the flow, otherwise this would be a lot easier :).

Comment: Instead of floating the divs, you can do `display: inline-block;`. This fixes most of the floated divs problem and doesn't mess up the flow.

Comment: Not sure if I get what you want. The divs left and right should start at the same (top) position?

Comment: Hugo, the first fiddle I posted shows what I want to happen visually: two sets of floated elements that are independent of each other WITHOUT being split into separate container elements.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without being split into separate container elements sadly..

Comment: Looks like Sifu was right, this is not possible without placing the elements in floated divs, which breaks the sequential order of items in the form. I wrote an AngularJS directive which takes care of this problem for me, for anyone interested its here: http://jsfiddle.net/84b5aov8/

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the float property of `.right` class to left, like this:

```
.right
{
    float: left;
    background: #BAB1E5;
}
```

[Fiidle.](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/93Ljqb36/8/)

Comment: Sadly it pushes down the left column, he needs them to stack.